# Brushless motor from RC car won't spin with even small resistance

Tags: brushless-motor, esc, radio-control

I recently bought a RC car kit and after 10 minutes it stopped going.

When I throttle, I can see the motor trying to spin but it will just grind and get hot quite fast.

The motor does move if I disconnect it from the big gear, but not as fast as it did when new and it will still get very hot. Also, I can stop it with my fingers with a very slight touch.

I don't know anything about motors or ESCs, so I'm not sure if my problem is the motor or the ESC.  Did I burn it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to check:

First, does the gear assembly work smoothly? If it doesn't, then the motor might have broken when attempting to work against too much resistance.

Second, if you apply a reasonable voltage directly to the positive and negative leads of the DC motor, does it still get hot and not work? If so then the motor is toast.

I cannot imagine that the mechanical issue is caused by the ESC.

Comment: yep, seems like it is. I'll try to have it replaced under warranty. It barely lasted 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a burnt (shorted) motor.

If you are not able to inspect the ESC with an oscilloscope, try connecting every combination of the motor leades to each other and spin the motor by hand. If only one phase is damaged, then one combination of phase wires connected to each other will provide more resistance than the other two.